# Inserting HTML elements in div tag via JavaScript without removing each other

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to something like very simple text editor. I need to provide functionality for the user to insert 7 different types of HTML elements and use them to create some custom form. Just to try how things work I made this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">



function MinMax() {
document.getElementById("EditorArea").innerHTML = "<table border= 1px><tr><td>Element</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td></tr><tr><td>Marked as</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Min</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Max</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Преди ремонт</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>След ремонт</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Time before</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Time after</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td></table>";
   //var elem = document.createElement("<table><tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th></tr><tr><td>Peter</td><td>Griffin</td></table>");
};

function ShowDate() {
document.getElementById("EditorArea").innerHTML = "<p class='dateTime' style='width:120px; border: 2px solid black'>DateTime</p>";
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="MinMax()">MinMax</button>
<button type="button" onclick="ShowDate()">DateTime</button>
<div id="EditorArea" style = "width:800px; height:600px; border:2px solid black;">
```

The problem I have is that I can't find a way to add a whole table structure using `insertBefore` or `insertAfter`. However `innerHTML` does it but when I add another element it removes the previous. Even though I still don't know how I will let the user arrange the different elements to make it look like he wants, for now I need a way to add several elements  without this behavior - the old element to be removed by the new one.

Comment: Have you considered using JQuery or something alike?

Comment: Dunno. Anyways I need some simple solution if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this, but i recomend to use jquery.

```
document.getElementById("EditorArea").innerHTML = document.getElementById("EditorArea").innerHTML + "your content";
```

jquery

```
$(div).append(data);
```

Comment: But it will add a `tr, td` outside of `table`

Answer (score 3):

### Use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.insertAdjacentHTML)

[image]

### <kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zNcZG/)**</kbd>

```
function MinMax() {
    document.getElementById("EditorArea").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',"<table border= 1px><tr><td>Element</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td></tr><tr><td>Marked as</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Min</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Max</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Преди ремонт</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>След ремонт</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Time before</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Time after</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td></table>");
};

function ShowDate() {
    document.getElementById("EditorArea").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<p class='dateTime' style='width:120px; border: 2px solid black'>DateTime</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use += instead of =

```
document.getElementById("EditorArea").innerHTML += "<p class='dateTime' style='width:120px; border: 2px solid black'>DateTimelt</p>";
```